# Joining two self-written doubly-LinkedLists in Java constructor

Tags: java, join, constructor, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I would like to create a third list by connecting 2 others. I tried to do it, but as I expected my idea was wrong and everything doesn't work fine. Below you can see List file and test program. The other (empty) constructors of List are meant to connect 2 lists by adding elements of one List before specific index of the second list, and adding elements of one List before specific element of the second one using equals() method. It will be also hard for me for sure, but I ask only for simply connecting elements to obtain something like that: 
(L11, L12, L13)+(L21, L22, L23) = L11,L12,L13,L21,L22,L23

```
public class Lista implements List {
private Element head = new Element(null); //wartownik
private int size; 
public Lista(){
    clear();
}

public Lista(Lista lista1, Lista lista2) {
        head.previous = lista2.head.previous;
        head.next = lista1.head.next;
}

public Lista(Lista lista1, Lista lista2, int index) {

}

public Lista(Lista lista1, Lista2. Object value) {

}

public void clear(){
    head.setPrevious(head);
    head.setNext(head);
    size=0;
}

public void insert(int index, Object value) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
   if (index<0 || index>size) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
   Element element = new Element(value);
   element.wstawPrzed(getElement(index));
   ++size;
}

public Element getElement(int index) {
   Element szukany = head.getNext();
   for (int i=index; i>0; --i) 
       szukany = szukany.getNext();   
   return szukany;
}


 public Object get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
    if(index<0 || index>size) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    Element particular = head.getNext();
    for(int i=0; i <= index; i++)
        particular = particular.getNext();
    return particular.getValue();
}  

public boolean delete(Object o){
    if(head.getNext() == null) return false;
    if(head.getNext().getValue().equals(o)){
        head.setNext(head.getNext().getNext());
        size--;
        return true;
    }

    Element delete = head.getNext();
    while(delete != null && delete.getNext() != null){
        if(delete.getNext().getValue().equals(o)){
            delete.setNext(delete.getNext().getNext());
                            size--;
            return true;
        }
        delete = delete.getNext();
    }
    return false;
}

public int size(){
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return size == 0;
}

public void infoOStanie() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("Lista pusta.");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Lista zawiera " + size() + " elementow.");
  }

}

public IteratorListowy iterator() {
    return new IteratorListowy();
}

public void wyswietlListe() {
    System.out.println();
    IteratorListowy iterator = iterator();
    for (iterator.first(); !iterator.isDone(); iterator.next())
    {
        System.out.println(iterator.current());
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private static final class Element{
    private Object value; 
    private Element next; //Referencja do kolejnego obiektu
    private Element previous; //Referencja do elementu poprzedniego

    public Element(Object value){ 
        setValue(value); 
      }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    //ustawia referencję this.next na obiekt next podany w atgumencie
    public void setNext(Element next) {
        if (next != null)
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Element getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public void setPrevious(Element previous) {
        if (previous != null)
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public Element getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public void wstawPrzed(Element next) {
        Element previous = next.getPrevious();
        setNext(next);
        setPrevious(previous);
        next.setPrevious(this);
        previous.setNext(this);
    } 

    public void delete() {
        previous.setNext(next);
        next.setPrevious(previous);
    }

}

private class IteratorListowy implements Iterator{
private Element current;

public IteratorListowy() {
   current = head;
} 

public void next() {
   current = current.next;
}   

public void previous() {
   current = current.previous;
}

 public boolean isDone() {
   return current == head;
} 
public Object current() {
    return current.value;
}

public void first() {
   current = head.getNext();
}

public void last() {
   current = head.getPrevious();
}
}
}
```

test

```
public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Lista lista1 = new Lista();
  Lista lista2 = new Lista();
  Lista lista3 = new Lista(lista1, lista2);
  Student s1 = new Student("Kowalski", 3523);
  Student s2 = new Student("Polański", 45612);
  Student s3 = new Student("Karzeł", 8795);
  Student s4 = new Student("Pałka", 3218);
  Student s5 = new Student("Konowałek", 8432);
  Student s6 = new Student("Kłopotek", 6743);
  Student s7 = new Student("Całka", 14124);
  Student s8 = new Student("Pabin", 1258);
  Student s9 = new Student("Dryjas", 7896);
  Student s10 = new Student("Zając", 5642);
  lista1.insert(0, s1);
  lista1.insert(0, s2);
  lista1.insert(0, s3);
  lista1.insert(0, s4);
  lista1.insert(0, s5);
  lista1.wyswietlListe();
  lista1.infoOStanie();

  lista2.insert(0, s6);
  lista2.insert(0, s7);
  lista2.insert(0, s8);
  lista2.insert(0, s9);
  lista2.insert(0, s10);
  lista2.wyswietlListe();
  lista2.infoOStanie();

  lista3.wyswietlListe();

}
}
```

Comment: If you really implement `List`, you implement `Collection`. Which means you have `.addAll()`, right?

Comment: noo. It's doubly-LinkedList, but all methods are self-written, so I haven't addAll method. I want to write something like it, but prefer it to be constructor of third List. I'm struggling with Lista(lista1, lista2) constructor

Comment: So, your "implements List" at the beginning of your code does not mean "java.util.List"?

Comment: ah...no. It's simple interface written by myself with containing simple methods like size, insert, IsEmpty

Comment: The "next" and "previous" variables in Element are private. In Lista(Lista lista1, Lista lista2) you try to access them directly , which is not allowed. Use the setNext, getNext, setPrevious, and getPrevious methods that you wrote in the Element class.

Comment: @mikebolt `Element` is a nested class, he can access whatever members of it he wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you are trying to concatenate two doubly linked lists `list1` and `list2`, so you would need this simple logic :

```
// tail of list1 should point to head of list2
lista1.tail.next = lista2.head;

// as we are doubly linked, head of list2 should point back to tail of list1
lista2.head.previous = lista1.tail
```

this is it, the head of the list1 will now be the head of result list.

Now, doing it in your constructor :

```
public Lista(Lista lista1, Lista lista2) {
    // get hold of lisa1.tail
    Element lista1Tail = lista1.getElement(lista1.size() - 1);
    listaTail.next = lista2.head;

    //now pointer back to tail of lista1
    lista2.head.previous = listaTail;
}
```

This will work, given you fix your getElement() method (which now return not correct index) and add null pointer checks for boundary cases.

As a simpler alternative, I recommend keeping `tail` member of your list, it is cleaner and more performant.

Comment: hmm...but...sry, i don't understand at all :) I will try to create something like tail (now i have hadtail as one element. Logic from the middle of your post (Element lista1tail = lista1.getElement(lista1.size() - 1);
        lista1tail.next = lista2.head;
        lista2.head.previous = lista1tail;) don't work. It runs infinitely showing null,null,null...

Comment: well, that is because your getElement() does not return correct value. Try testing getElement(0), and getElement(yourListSize) and you'd be surprized with the results. You have to fix it first

Comment: huh. Why is that so? It looks good for me, and it runs properly with other methods @edit; ok. I will check it

Comment: minimum fix to your `getElement` is to use `Element szukany = head;` instead of `head.getNext()`. Please check it yourself

Comment: I see that you can be right of course (which is not surprise to me :) ). I assume that you're solution for my topic problem is correct and that my getElement() is now ok ( i will analyse, why :) ). I think now I need to think about wyswietlListe() method, which throws NullPointerExpection now :D

Comment: Program runs, wyswietlListe(lista3) shows elements from lista1 and then it stops with nullpointerexecption, so I don't know in fact. I need to look closer (and in my case really looonger) at it :)

Comment: god..but now I need to sleep as I don't see anything already. Thank you for your ideas. I marked it accepted as I'm sure you're right and I'm hard to work with :)

Comment: And it is definitely not about being right or wrong, I am just trying to help. If you think you can understand better with clear head tomorrow, do that, just let me know if you are still stuck. Good luck

Comment: You're really kind :) yep...in current version I have constructor of new list written as you told me. When I create lista3 = new Lista(lista1, lista2) in program and then use lista3.wyswietlListe() it throws NullPointerException in the first step in for loop. So I think there is mistake somewhere making my iterator not working well. wait...in the constructor there is no definiciton of head.next, so I assume it's null. let's see...

Comment: yup...that was one of problems. I've added head.next = lista1.head.next; and now there no errors it write five elements from first list, then...null and everything again infinately. I think, all I need now is good definition of head.previous

Comment: I've tried head.previous = lista2.getElement(lista2.size()-1); but it's not correct. Program acts exactly the same. @Edit: to be accurate it now prints: 9 elements (two joined lists had 10) then null, and from this moment it returns 5 elements from first list - null, 5 elements - null etc. Infinitely. So I think i'm close if I managed to show 9 of 10 elements :)

Comment: Can you do this simple check : Just for your lista1 of 5 elems, try to see whether you get the tail element correctly, i.e. print value of `getElement(lista1.size() - 1)`, and it verify it is the last one. May be you don't need `-1` ?

Comment: yes. I didn't need -1. After my new changes, program shows all 10 elements, but of course then it prints null and starts to print craps. I abandoned idea of constructor of third list and simple added method addAll(Lista lista) to Lista class. I assume now my only problem is head.previous. The method looks like that:

Comment: public void addAll(Lista lista2) {
      Element lista1tail = getElement(size());    
        lista1tail.next = lista2.head.next;    
        lista2.head.previous = lista1tail;   
        head.previous = lista2.getElement(lista2.size());    
            size = size+lista2.size();    
    }

Comment: well, this is not correct. Change it according to what I put in my answer : replace `lista1tail.next = lista2.head.next;` with `lista1tail.next = lista2.head;` and remove `head.previous = lista2.getElement(lista2.size());`

Comment: Ok. now I have: Element lista1tail = getElement(size());
        lista1tail.next = lista2.head;
        lista2.head.previous = lista1tail;
            size = size+lista2.size(); and it works worse. It prints null after elements of first list and then prints elements of second. Of course everything runs infinately. lista1tail.next = lista2.head.next; works better without null in the middle

Comment: I recommend you implement simple printing method, without iterator(because I suspect the problem is in your iterator) and verify what you have now first. So, just implement method : `static void printList(List list) { Element current = list.head; while(current!=null) { System.out.println(current.value); current = current.next;}`

Comment: You've forgotten that all those fields are private :) But of course I implemented method inside List class: public void printList() {
    { Element current = head; 
    while(current!=null) { 
        System.out.println(current.value);
    }
    current = current.next;}
    }   aaaand...you will never guess a result :) It prints: null,null,null,null infinately :)

Comment: you want me, to send you something?

Comment: no, I am trying your code from the post. It is totally broken. I cant even print the original list (without concatenation) , because `insert` is incorrect.

Comment: I will put extra method called `add` which will add to the end of the list and confirm that my solution works, you will have to fix the rest yourself.

Comment: no, its fine. I am going to use your original code, make modifications to make it work and then put them on pastebin so you could verify. Just give me 10 mins please

Comment: I added these changes to your original code (the one in the question, not in your answer) : http://pastebin.com/tgVxjBvh Everything in testing `main` method works as expected. There are still many things to fix in your code, but please do it yourself, I won't have time for that. Hope that helps

Comment: yes, indeed :) It works finally. Now I need to repair insert method to be usable. But the problem is solved. Thank for spending so much time helping me :)